# AWS IOT Thing search with iot.listThings() with both thingTypeName and attributes

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, iot

In AWS IOT Javascript SDK,

I am not able to do iot.listThings() with both thingTypeName and attribute
with code as below

```
  let listThingsRequest = 
  {
      "thingTypeName": "mythingtype",
      "attributeName": "state",
      "attributeValue": "registered"
  }


  // List all iotThings based on search criteria in listThingsRequest
  export const listThings = async (listThingsRequest: ListThingsRequest) => {
    return iot.listThings(listThingsRequest).promise()
  }
```

I get a error message as below,

```
"Listing things by the combination of attribute and thing type is not supported."
```

Is this the expected behaviour or am I missing something?
It would be a useful feature to be able to search by both of them,

Answer (score 1):

Did not found any documentation according to this, but CLI fails also:
[image: CLI iot list things fails]

In the [API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_ListThings.html#API_ListThings_ResponseElements) You can find only a list of possible error responses but not the full list of errors, which is kind of uncool, but I suppose this list would be very long.
In my opinion this is just not supported as the error message states and it is not only SDK specific, when the CLI command also fails. If You want AWS to support them You should probably have to open a internal ticket for that. I wnt through this process some time ago and it takes some time for them to implement even small features.

Comment: Thanks, raised a AWS issue. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/4237

Comment: You should open a case in the AWS support center, as this is not the problem of the SDK, but of the IoT service itself.